# Reporting variance estimates for mixed models

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures

When using a mixed model to analyze some data, is it common to report the variance estimates of the random effects in a publication, for example for a medical journal?

I don't see how this information would be of interest to the reader and therefore was not sure if we should include it. If yes, should we also include a measure of uncertainty?

Comment: As with most things, it depends on the context. For example, if you recruited students that were nested in schools, it might be very important to understand how much variability in the outcome is explained at the school level. I have reported estimated variances from RE models where I was interested in how community of residence was related to child growth. Hopefully these examples will help you find others, because there are plenty published papers that do this out there.

Answer (score 1):

- Some authors report the random effects variances directly. See for example [Wicht, Ludwig-Mayerhofer (2014) *The impact of neighborhoods and schools on young people’s occupational aspirations*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001879114001079) table 2. sometimes the variances are reported as portions of the total variance: see e.g. Tables 3 and 4 in [Lenkeit (2010) *How effective are educational systems? A value-
  added approach to measure trends in PIRLS*](http://www.j-e-r-o.com/index.php/jero/article/viewFile/317/157).
- A very frequent way of reporting variance attributed to random effects is the [intraclass correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#Modern_ICC_definitions:_simpler_formula_but_positive_bias) (*ICC*), which is a combination of the random intercepts variance and the residual variance. There are [so many articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2016&q=intraclass+correlation&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5) reporting the ICC ([also in medicine](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=intraclass+correlation+medicine&btnG=&hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2016&oq=intraclass+correlation+medici)), that it is not fair to pick one specific ;)